# Words play - does it have a special name in English? How to do the same with 'security' word for example?

Tags: word-usage, american-english, british-english

By looking at this picture: [image]

Or at the title of this album: [image]

You can see that the authors used there something which I call a word game. My question is, does doing so has an official name?

How can I come up with similar examples, with given words, for instance, with *security* word?

Comment: It is called ***pun:***
a play on words, sometimes on different senses of the same word and sometimes on the similar sense or sound of different words. 
http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pun

Comment: Coming up with new puns involves imagination and inventiveness. There's not much we can tell you about those.

Comment: I think OP's examples are just "visual puns". There's a well-known type of "word puzzle" called a [dingbat](http://www.kensquiz.co.uk/table-top-quizzes/word-puzzles/dingbats/), but that normally only involves letters and digits (and sometimes simple line drawings).

Comment: If you mean with the word "security":  "Drink Securitea, the hot beverage that gives you a feeling of safety."

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'd always heard them referred to as [rebus](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/rebus?s=t) puzzles. Though now the [dingbat font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dingbat) makes more sense.

Comment: I've always understood a difference between **Word Games:** such as 

wordsearch, Codeword, crossword puzzle, 

Scrabble,  Lexicon, 

hangman and riddles; and another group known as  

**Word play:** 

Pig Latin, Rebus puzzles, Puns,  Playground Riddles, Puns, Secret Messages,

Comment: The general term is *wordplay*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shooting from the hip here, but I would call it a:

**[homonym](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/homonym)-[pun](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pun)**